# How to make another request with Python requests if the response of the first one is Foo?

Tags: python, python-requests

I make a request into outer API:

```
with requests.Session() as api:
            user = requests.post(URL, data=json.dumps(post_obj), headers=headers)
            try:
                user.raise_for_status()
            except HTTPError as e:
                return Response(
                    status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
                )
```

After I get the response, I save it into my database. Now if I get back information I already have in my db, I should make another request into another url. Can I make it inside the `with requests.Session()`?

Comment: The whole *point* of a `Session` is to perform multiple requests!  It will maintain various parameters for you, rather than having to specify them again for each request, and in particular it will maintain cookie values.  If the "another url" is on the same server, then the maintained cookies might be useful, perhaps even necessary for the second request to succeed.  If it's on an entirely different server, then the cookies might constitute a leak of private information.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for the answer. How can I make a another request for example if the response body of the first request contains "foo": "bar"? Is that possible?